# Why are these different?

Tags: c

Can someone explain me why these two functions have different outputs?

```c
void remove_index (int s[],int n, int N){
while (n < N - 1) s[n] = s[n+1],n++;
}


void remove_index (int s[],int n, int N){
while (n < N - 1) s[n] = s[++n];
}
```

Comment: 2nd version reads and writes `n` without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @ikegami No, 2nd version.

Comment: also consider `while (n++ < N - 1) s[n-1] = s[n];`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm wondering about your mind-reading skills!

Comment: @DiogoVieira If `n` is 5 immediately before `s[n] = s[++n]` runs then, as part of working out what to assign, the right hand side of the expression (`s[++n]`) is evaluated first, what value do you think `n` will have when it is time to evaluate `s[n]`?

Comment: I suspect both `s[n] = ...,n++;` and  `s[n] = s[++n];` are UB as the increment of `n` is not sequenced  with `s[n]`.